# Mac Pro early2008 El Cap. LOGIC BOARD compatibility w/ later models

Tags: mac-pro, compatibility, motherboard

I just found this site today and it looks sweet! I believe I need to replace the logic board in my unit. Would a board from a 2009 or newer work on my 2008 Mac pro currently with 2x Intel quad 2.8ghz (part 661-4449)? I would like to know in order to expand on the availability of used parts out there and possibly score a faster processor.

Answer (score 1):

No. The machines are totally different as soon as you take the side off, visually & electronically.

The top ⅓ is visually similar, though the 08 uses PATA connections in the optical bay, the 09 has SATAII.

As for the rest, these are just the visible highlights...

The 08 mounts the CPUs directly to the motherboard, 'sideways' like a standard PC, with separate removable RAM daughterboards onto which individual sticks are installed.
At the front is a large dual fan assembly.

[image] [image]

<sup>*08 pics EveryMac & OWC*</sup>

The 2009 has an entirely different structure - both the CPUs & RAM are on a removable daughterboard, the huge front fan assembly has been replaced by a single fan & a nice PCI card release, far improved over the 08's 'fiddle around underneath like a PC' structure.

[image]

<sup>*09 pic OWC*</sup>

OWC's picture also hints at *(well, advertises;-)* one more thing about the 09.
It can reasonably simply be upgraded to 2012 5,1 firmware & will take dual 6-core Westmere's rather than the original Nehalems.
It can also be updated to Sierra 10.12 once the firmware has been upgraded.

I forgot to mention that the memory isn't compatible either.
The 08 takes DDR2 [expensive these days]
The 08 takes DDR3 [much cheaper]

Also, & you really can't tell without sitting two side by side, the drive sleds are different sizes. To move a drive from an 08 to an 09 you must use the correct sled or the pins don't match up to the motherboard when you slide them in.

The 08's still a good machine for its age, but the 09 upgraded to [actually higher than originally purchasable] 2012 spec is still quite the beast.

I have one of each, 08 & upgraded 09. Both going strong.

Purely my own opinion, but I'd be tempted to trade up the 08 to an 09 - you can get them very easily on eBay etc, fully upgraded & ready to go. [Mine is a dual 6-core 3.46GHz, 64GB RAM, cost £1600, UKP. I added a decent graphics card & still had change from 2 grand.]

Comment: Thanks for that breakdown. I had no idea Apple changed the models so much. If I decide to trade up to a 2009 will I be ab!e to use my memory sticks and SSDs that are in my '08? You mentioned the drive sleds are different. And I saw at OWC the '09 used a 2.5" drive.

Comment: The memory isn't compatible either [I should add that to my answer] The 08 is DDR2, [now very expensive] & the 09 DDR3 [comparatively cheap]. Assuming your SSD is SATA then yes, you can carry it over. If you have it mounted in one of the sleds you'd have to re-mount it to the new sled in the 09, or the pins won't seat at the back. Presumably any 2.5-3.5 adapter you already have will need to move with it. I successfully carried an SSD [in the optical bay] & 4 HDs [by changing sleds] over to my 09 - it even booted straight to the moved drive with no further tweaking required.